# Fitting a function that contains a numerical derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics, mathematical-optimization

Imagine I want to Fit a data to a simple function as following:

```
    f[c]=ND[Exp[c x],x,??]
FindFit[data,f[c],c]
```

where ND is numerical derivative.
Could you please tell me what can put instead of "??" for this function to do fitting.

Thanks a lot

Comment: E.g. `data = Table[{x, Pi*Exp[Pi x]}, {x, -5., 5.}]; f[c_, x0_] := ND[Exp[c x], x, x0]; FindFit[data, f[c, x], c, x]`? -- Might want `f[c_, x0_] := Block[{x}, ND[Exp[c x], x, x0]];`

Comment: @Michael E2 Thank you so much

Comment: @Michael E2 may I have your email address? I have a problem